# Error "Type 'PageTwo' does not conform to protocol 'View'"

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Working on a swift app in storyboard. And this error is thrown and I have no idea why

Line that the error is thrown on:

`struct PageTwo: View {`

Entire file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


struct PageTwo: View {
class PageTwo: UIViewController {

    var body: some View {
       Text("eugh")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The `body` is not in the struct.

Comment: https://medium.com/@max.codes/use-uiviewcontrollers-in-swiftui-views-with-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable-coordinator-5b5f75e45caf

Comment: can't do that. If u want used UIViewController, U need used to UIViewControllerRepresentable

Comment: Thank you George, Your reply Fixed my issue!